# Нарисовать фукцию

Tags: java, алгоритм, swing

Я в целях практики написал код, который должен выводить функцию на экран. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что при выводе функции по типу `Math.log(X) * Y == Math.sin(X * Y)//true`, приходится увеличивать точность до миллиардных. На графике в форме квадрата от -5 до 5 придётся проверить 100000000000000000000 значений, и потратить на это очень много времени. Есть ли способ оптимизировать это?

код:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

class FrameHandler{

    //основные переменные для установки информации
    private static BufferedImage img;
    private static Graphics2D g2d;

    //константы
    private static final double deep = 500; //смещение графика в сторону отрицательных значений
    private static final double width = 1000;//минимальная длина линии проходящей через центр графика, и касающейся обоих границ экрана, как ширина или высота квадрата 
    private static final double zoom = 100;//увеличение масштаба, и уменьшение области допустимых значений... В общем "приближение"
    private static final double accur = 1000000000;//точность, если значение = 1, то вариант 1.9,1.1 и тд рассматриваться не будут как возможно соответствующие функции

    //окно
    static JFrame jFrame = getFrame();
    static JButton jButton = new JButton();

    //определяем компоненты
    private static void init() {
        jFrame.add(jButton);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        jButton.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
    }

    //присваеваем значения
    private static void setVars(){
        img = new BufferedImage((int)width,(int)width,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
    }

    //обрабатываем функцию и устанавливаем картинку
    public static void mainMethod(){
        setVars();
        clear();
        check_drawAtAllCells();
        init();
        imageToPanel();
    }

    //пробегаемся по полю
    private static void check_drawAtAllCells(){
        for (double X = 0; X < width / zoom * accur; X++){
            for (double Y = 0; Y < width / zoom * accur; Y++){
                if (checkTheFunc(X / (width / zoom * accur / width), Y / (width / zoom * accur / width))){
                    System.out.println(X / (width / zoom * accur / width) + " " + Y / (width / zoom * accur / width));
                    draw(X / (width / zoom * accur / width), Y / (width / zoom * accur / width));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //проверяем условие
    private static boolean checkTheFunc(double X, double Y){
        double imX = ((double) X - (double) deep) / (double) zoom;
        double imY = ((double) Y - (double) deep) / (double) zoom;

        return Math.log(imX) * imY == Math.sin(imY * imX);//наше уравнение
    }

    //рисуем
    private static void draw(double X, double Y){
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect((int)X - 1,(int)Y - 1,3,3);
    }

    //сила в чистоте))
    private static void clear(){
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0,0,(int)width,(int)width);
    }

    //задаём картинку панели
    private static void imageToPanel(){
        jButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        jButton.setSize((int)width,(int)width);
        jButton.repaint();
        jFrame.repaint();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    //определяем окно
    static JFrame getFrame(){
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize((int)width,(int)width);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        return jFrame;
    }
}
```

В код не попало, что я вызываю из метода `Main.main(String args)` метод `mainMethod()`

Comment: Что-то не понимаю, зачем? Как вы ее строите? Как я понимаю, надо пройти по X, вычисляя для каждого Y, и все?

Comment: Что такое "график в форме квадрата от -5 до 5"?

Comment: @Harry нет, вы говорите про линейное уравнение. У меня же для каждого X может быть бесконечное количество Y и наоборот.

Comment: @igor при отрисовке мы видим квадрат, у которого левый верхний угол - (-5,-5), а правый нижний - (5,5). На этом "квадрате" я и вывожу функцию.

Comment: Зачем делать вычисления 100000000000000000000 (не знаю, как называется это число) раз? У Вас нет столько пикселей.

Comment: Посмотрите http://bit.ly/3lHYl1y В этом диапазоне нет такого количества (бесконечного) ветвей... Одна ветвь очевидна - y=0, остальные симметричны в силу нечетности обеих частей, так что для каждого y можно поискать x... Каким именно методом - немного второй вопрос. Ньютона, хорд, деления пополам...

Comment: @Igor значения как (X.XXXXXX;Y.YYYYYYYY) тоже надо проверить. Ранее `accur` равнялся 10000, и большинство подобных функций выводились точками на графике. То есть приравняв `accur` к 1000000000, я начал рассматривать в 1000000 раз больше значений. Но спорить не буду (3.66666666666666666666;3.66666666666666666666) и (3.66666666666666666667;3.66666666666666666666) окрасят один и тот же пиксель.

Comment: @Harry https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieVlQVtjalY тайм-код: 2:40

Comment: Там совсем другая функция! Там логарифм `y` по основанию `x`. А вы что написали в вопросе?...

Comment: Если честно, я с логарифмами знаком только поверхностно. Я лишь в девятом классе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбираясь в данном вопросе, я понял, что тратить меньше времени, или по другому оптимизировать программу нельзя, но есть выход в, виде рассматривания знака равенства как "примерно равно", то есть я просто начал округлять до целой выражения по обе стороны знака равенства. Вполне себе решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

График неявной функции так не строится.

Во-первых, нужно немножко изучить функцию. Видно, что X всегда положительно, значит - второй и третий квадранты нас не интересуют.

Одна ветвь решения - луч `Y=0`.

Кроме того, две ветви решения симметричны относительно оси `OX`.

Следовательно, используем следующую стратегию: проходим диапазон `Y` от малого положительного значения до нужного предела с неким шагом. Для каждого `Y` **численно** решаем уравнение для `X`,

```
ln(X)*Yi=sin(Yi*X)
```

ставим точку, соединяем отрезком с предыдущей точкой.

Итого получится нечто вроде гиперболы (и симметричная ей с отрицательными Y) c интересными извивами в районе `Y=2*Pi*K`

Comment: Я неправильно объяснил, что мне нужно. Так что минусовать не буду. Меня интересовал вопрос оптимизации, Чтоб можно было построить график любой функции, а не частный случай.

Comment: Что мешает применить "стратегию" к другим функциям? Нашли точку, от неё мелкими шажками двигаемся. Без исследования функции в общем случае будет туго. Посерьёзнее подходец: [Любая функция](https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/public_user/mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf)

Comment: А в чём минус автоматизации?

Comment: Какой автоматизации?

Comment: Вы предлагаете, придумывать решение для каждого частного случая. Мой вопрос состоял в том, чтоб рисовать любую функцию, только введя условие в метод `checkTheFunc(double, double)`.

Answer (score 0):

Имеем неявную функцию

```
F(x,y) = G(x,y)
```

или

```
Z(x,y) = 0, где Z(x,y) = F(x,y) - G(x,y)
```

Это эквивалентно сечению трехмерной поверхности плоскостью `Z = 0`.

Как найти точки пересечения плоскости и поверхности для построения графика? Пройти по пикселам отображаемой области, проверяя, что знак Z в точке (x,y) отличается от знака в точках справа (x+1,y) и снизу (x,y+1). Знак разный - поставили точку. Для обычной отображаемой области типа 500x500 пикселов это будет всего 750000 проверок (втрое меньше, если результаты запоминать в таблице).

Нужен другой масштаб - область остаётся той же самой, только пиксельные координаты масштабируются на меньший диапазон реальных координат, т.е. вычислений столько же.

Вот практический результат для вашей функции. Справа область загогулины в 50-кратном масштабе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный код на Delphi. `fun` преобразует пиксельные координаты в реальные (по уму это преобразование должна делать отдельная функция) и вычисляет нужное значение.

```
var
  ix, iy: Integer;

  function fun(ix, iy: integer): Double;
  var
    x, y: Double;
  begin
    //y := (300 - iy) / 30;
    //x := ix / 30;
    y := (300 - iy) / 1500 + 2 * Pi;
    x := ix / 1500 +0.75;
    Result := ln(x)*y - sin(y*x);
  end;

begin

  for iy := 1 to 600 do begin
    for ix := 1 to 600 do begin
      if (fun(ix, iy) * fun(ix + 1, iy) <= 0)
      or (fun(ix, iy) * fun(ix, iy + 1) <= 0)
      then
        Canvas.Pixels[ix, iy] := clRed;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: MBo
... Имеем неявную функцию... Шикарно!
просто нет слов!
Спасибо)