# Как отрисовать неявную функцию F(x; y) = 0?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt, математика

Пишу программу для отображения любых функций, что введёт пользователь, в том числе и неявных функций. Если с частью нахождения точек я справился(эти точки хранятся в std::vector), то вот с соединением этих точек линиями возникает проблема. В голову приходит такой алгоритм:

1. Выбрать значения Yi-1 и Y
2. Отсортировать значения x в этих точках
3. Если их расстояние соответствует шагу, то соединить линиями

Но проблема в том, что не все графики, как мне кажется, будут подходить для этого алгоритма и поэтому пришёл сюда с вопросом, а есть ли алгоритм лучше?
Может быть кто-то знает идею получше или реализовывал данный алгоритм?

Comment: Если точек будет много, то их и соединять может не нужно будет. Просто рисуйте их и всё

Comment: @KoVadim проблема в том, что это будет очень долго при большом масштабе(уже делал так). Да и для функций вроде x-sin(y^2) или sin(y)*y - ln(|x|)/sin(|x|) нужна большая точность, для нормального отображения. А хотелось бы иметь небольшое кол-во точек и просто соединять их, но вот как сделать это лучше, чем я описал выше, ума не приложу.

Comment: а тут другой способ. Когда масштаб увеличивается, не нужно пересчитывать все точки. Диапазон Вы уже знаете, какое то кол-во точек уже есть. Осталось немного посчитать ещё. В идеале, кол-во вычислений будет приблизительно одинаковое при разных масштабах

Comment: @KoVadim, тут просто проблема во времени нахождения таких точек. Если сделать точность 0.001, и отображать их сразу во весь экран, то обычно это занимало около 1-3 минут(3 минуты при отображении графиков с большим кол-вом точек). Тогда скорее нужно изменить алгоритм нахождения точек, тк у меня это происходит путем фиксирования y, и нахождения корней при разных x. Каким алгоритмом тогда можно заменить мой?

Comment: а Вам точно нужна такая "суперточность"? с другой стороны, можно такое сделать на фрагментном шейдере и работать будет точно быстро. Правда логику программы придется переделать

Comment: @KoVadim, просто бы хотелось однородности что-ли. Имею ввиду то, что для функций с одним аргументом(будь то x или fi) отображается все крайне быстро и без огрехов, а тут такой затуп где либо  мы жертвуем качеством для быстрого отображения, либо быстрым отображением ради качества.
Если не будет других вариантов, то буду на фрагментном шейдере делать, так как впринципе переписывания кода я не очень боюсь

Comment: ходите циклом не по точкам в реальных координатах, а по пикселям. и для каждого (возможно каждого n-того) пикселя по X считайте Y. тогда при любом масштабе точность будет какая нужно и не придется считать лишнего

Comment: [Пиксельный подход](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1260094/291659)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares

Comment: Спасибо всем :)